# Can't change custom keyboard layout in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout

I had a keyboard layout file in 18.04 (`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`), where I defined additional characters.
e.g.

```
...
    key <AD03> {        [         e,    E,      Greek_epsilon,  Greek_EPSILON]  };
...
```

This worked fine there. After switching to 22.04, this stopped working. To not change the whole file with an older version only the basic entry was edited.

```
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "English (US)";
```

When I pick the keyboard and check the layout, it appears correctly. (under the layout selection on the top bar)

[keyboard layout shows the epsilon character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPdaz.png)

However, in the applications, I am not able to use the character. AltGr + E does not print any character. In some applications it even triggers some shortcuts. I tried also CTRL + SHIFT + E. Still no success.
(I did relogin/rebooted to test the functionality.)

Comment: Have you defined AltGr as the "Alternate Characters Key"?

Comment: Thanks it did it. Can you submit it as an answer so that I can accept it? It is done under settings apparently. I have missed it completely.

Comment: Please feel free to submit an answer yourself. It's fine to answer your own question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is Gunnar's comment, which worked out for me.
Under Settings/Keyboard there is a field for "Alternate Characters Key", which can be set to "Right Alt" (nothing political here, just the right "Alt" key on the keyboard).
[Setting for alternate key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ozto.png)